# Jest mock a specific component from a module

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

What's the best way to do this so I'm not recreating the button structure all over again in my mock ?

Mocking a exported function component from a module of multiple components
Example:

```
jest.mock('@moduleComponents', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@moduleComponents'),
  Button: () => jest.fn(),
}))
```

Problem here is Button is an named exported component so () => jest.fn() breaks.
I can do:

```
jest.mock('@moduleComponents', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@moduleComponents'),
  Button: () => <div>fsdf</div,
}))
```

That works but I don't want to recreate the structure of the Button using JSX

**Context on what I'm trying to test:**

**Component**

```
import { Button } from '@moduleComponents'
const MyComponent = () => {
   const onClickHandler = () => {
     ....code in here
    }

   return(
       <div>
         <Button onClick={onClickHandler}>My Button</Button>
       </div>
    )
}
```

**test component:**

```
const mockedButton = jest.fn()

jest.mock('@moduleComponents', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@moduleComponents'),
 Button: () => mockedButton,
}))

test('button was fired once', () => {
  render(<MyComponent />)
  button = screen.getByText('My Button')
  fireEvent.click(button)
  expect(mockedButton).toBeCalled()
})
```

Comment: It's not clear why you're partially mocking a module to start with, that's generally not a good idea. Could you give a [mre] that shows the context?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I updated my post with context. It's common practice to mock the module and its functions. In this case the module is a bunch of components that are exported. I don;t have access to them but I want to mock one of them so I can test the click event and the code inside of it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe if you know of a better approach let me know. I don't think you can test inner functions on a functional component.

Comment: Why do you need to mock any component to test the click event? Mocking seems to be confusing you, if anything; the click doesn't call the mock function, _rendering_ does. Test the _behaviour_, the stuff you left out of the actual handler function.